# Confuse to choose framework for create hybrid application

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

hey i want to create hybrid application. i see lots of sites but i don't get any solutions. so please suggest me a best framework for create hybrid application.Main point my hybrid application is supported to google map so i have doubt that in hybrid app google map is supported or not?How is the performance regarding the speed. I heard about IONIC framework . it is the good or not? using this framework can i create google map in application. If any one have tutorial link please share . Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

There are various type of Framework available for hybrid application.

Yes no doubt you can go with Ionic framework. Simple do google with keyword 'Ionic app Google map' and you will see live examples. You can go with Codepen site.

One more nice framework is Sencha touch that is also completely support Maps.
For this you can read
 https://www.sencha.com/products/touch/